# Concat dataframe excel to an existing excel file with keys

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel

Currently, I have a pandas excel implementation

```
   df1 = pd.read_excel('acoustic_guitars.xlsx')
   df2 = pd.read_excel('acoustic_string.xlsx')
   df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=["key1", "key2"], ignore_index=False)
   df_final = df_final.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

However, we need to update our implementation to add concat the new created dataframe instead of getting all xlsx files, and concat them all, note: category here is dynamic

```
     if os.path.exists(f"{BASE_DIR}/masters.xlsx") and os.stat(f"{BASE_DIR}/master.xlsx").st_size != 0:
        print("it exists")
        # with pd.ExcelWriter("master.xlsx", mode='a', if_sheet_exists='error')  as writer:
        #     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=parent_category, index=False)
        master_pd = pd.read_excel("masters.xlsx")
        merged = pd.concat([master_pd, df], key=[category])
        merged.to_excel('masters.xlsx')
    else:
        print("it doesnt exists")
        # File doesn't exist or is empty, create a new file with the new sheet
        with pd.ExcelWriter("masters.xlsx") as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=parent_category, index=False, key=category)
```